# Pasar el contenido de un archivo .txt a un diccionario de Python

Tags: python, diccionarios

Tengo este archivo llamado *Personal.txt*:

> ```
> usuario;contraseña;nombre:apellido
>
> test;1234;test;personal
>
> test2;1234;test;kubo
>
> test3;1234;test;kubo2
> ```

Y me gustaría pasarlo a un Diccionario de *Python* con el siguiente formato:

```
 Administrativo = {
"test": {
    "nombre": "test",
    "apellido": "test",
    "password": "1234"
},
"test2": {
    "nombre": "test",
    "apellido": "kubo",
    "password": "1234"
},
"test3": {
    "nombre": "test",
    "apellido": "kubo2",
    "password": "1234"
}
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Itera por el fichero abierto (cada iteración te devolverá una línea). Usa `linea.strip().split(";")` para dividir esa línea en trozos. Usa los trozos para crear el diccionario correspondiente a esa línea. Añade ese diccionario creado al general, usando como clave uno de los trozos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daré por hecho que la primera fila del archivo tiene una errata en los separadores y en realidad es:

`usuario;contraseña;nombre;apellido`

Puedes hacerlo de varias formas, como por ejemplo con `csv` o `pandas`

Una aproximación para usar `csv` sería así:

```
def parse_data(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
        headers = []
        data = []
        for row in reader:
            if not headers:
                headers = row
            else:
                data.append(dict(zip(headers, row)))

    return {
        x['usuario']: {
            'nombre': x['nombre'],
            'apellido': x['apellido'],
            'password': x['contraseña']
        } for x in data
    }


output = parse_data('Personal.txt')
```

Y una aproximación con `pandas` podría ser algo similar a esto:

```
def parse_data_pandas(file_path):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=';')
    df.rename(columns={'contraseña': 'password'}, inplace=True)
    return df.set_index('usuario').T.to_dict()


output = parse_data('Personal.txt')
```

En caso de que no se necesitase el renombrado de columnas se podría simplificar, ahí ya decide cómo proceder.